# Can't call variable from another class

Tags: java, class

I'm making a simulation of mastermind game in java. The player guesses a 4-digit number picked by the computer. If the right digit is in the correct position, it is a Bull, if not--a Cow. I'm trying to set it in the Game class so that if it is 4 Bulls, the game ends. I created a new variable in the Game constructor called the Bulls that equals Bulls in the Oracle class, but it doesn't seem to work.  I tried to initialize the bulls within the Oracle constractor instead of in the method, but it doesn't seem to work either.  Any suggestions? I appreciate any help. The code is in the link below. sorry, it's kinda messy...
[Look at pic called the BullsGame and the Oracle pics](https://www.flickr.com/photos/69370850@N04/?savedsettings=13223612935#photo13223612935)

This is how I tried to called the variable bulls from the class Oracle, of which computer is an object:

```
computer = new Oracle();
theBulls = computer.bulls;
turns = 0;
input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and then I'm trying to use it here:

```
if (theBulls == 4){
System.out.print("Thanks for playing!");
}
else{
more code
```

Comment: It'd be so much better if you actually shared the code, than trying to explain it or showing pictures.

Comment: From your description, I have no idea what you're trying to do or what problems you're having... code?

Comment: Post the relevant code here only, people doesn't have time to go through entire photo album.

Comment: I just added the code. could you look at it again, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `main` method creates a `new Game()`, that contructor creates a `new Oracle()`.

The `Oracle` constructor does not specify a value for `bulls`, so it defaults to `0`.

The `Game` constructor continues, and copies this `0` value into `theBulls`.

Then you call `g.play()` which eventually checks `theBulls == 4`.  This will always fail because `theBulls` has never changed from `0`.

I suspect you are imagining that `theBulls = computer.bulls` will make `theBulls` automagically update as `computer.bulls` varies.  This is not the case.

A simple solution is to change your `if` condition to

```
if (computer.bulls == 4) {
```